# Is there a make_tuple for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

Is there a make_tuple equivalent for C#/.NET? I want to do something like this

```
mylist.Add(new Tuple<string,int>("", 1));
```

C# seems to support it when i create my own function

```
Tuple<T, U> make_tuple<T, U>(T t, U u) { return new Tuple<T, U>(t, u); }
...
var a = make_tuple(1, ""); //compiles!
```

But [msdn tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) shows not using it

```
  Tuple<string, Nullable<int>>[] scores = 
                { new Tuple<string, Nullable<int>>("Jack", 78),
                  new Tuple<string, Nullable<int>>("Abbey", 92), 
                  ...
```

Is there or isn't there? I can use 4.5

Comment: Tuple classes are introducted since .NET 4.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [`Tuple.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create.aspx) method:

```
var a = Tuple.Create(1, "");
```

Comment: They really should use it in their examples. +1 and accept when I can